# why i am getting undifine when i console req.query?

Tags: node.js, express, req.query

this is api.js file

```
function apiKey(res, req, next) {
  const api_key = '12345678';
  console.log(req.query);
  next();
}

module.exports = apiKey;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Because req is the response object...

Answer (score 0):

You named it wrong way. should be like this

```
function apiKey(req, res, next) {
 const api_key = '12345678';
 console.log(req.query);
 next();
}
```

module.exports = apiKey;